# VLC on 4K monitor only shows video in upper left quarter of VLC window (and a bit outside)

Tags: vlc-media-player, 4k-resolution

I recently got a new 4K monitor and now whenever I play a video on this monitor, VLC only displays the video in the upper left quarter of the screen, when it's running in a window or full screen.  When running in a window, the video display is actually somewhat falls slightly outside (to the left) of the main VLC window.

The resolution of the video makes no difference.

I tried a different player, Media Player Classic Home Cinema, and it plays it perfectly, but I would rather figure out how to get VLC to work.

I am running Windows 10 with a GTX 1060 video card.

I have completely no idea where to even start looking to troubleshoot this, I've done a fair amount of googling but haven't found anyone else with this problem.

Comment: Does your setup have dual-monitors? VLC will use the resolution of the main screen.

Comment: It does, and the main screen is 4K.  Regardless, wouldn't it adjust as you switch screens?

Comment: No, this is a problem with VLC.

Comment: But, VLC is opening on the main (4K) screen, yet displaying in 1080....???  Surely it's capable of playing 4K content?

Comment: Who would downvote a question about a legitimate technical issue?

Answer (score 4):

On VLC Shortcut:

Right click, Properties, Compatibility, Change High DPI Settings

High DPI Scaling Override
   Override high DPI scaling behavior: Checked
   Scaling performed by: select Application

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is a known problem with VLC on a computer with dual monitors.
For best results the two monitors should have the same resolution.

As VLC is a Qt application, you might try to create an environment variable
called `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR` with the value of `0`

You might also raise the question on the
[The VideoLAN Forums](https://forum.videolan.org/),
where you might get an answer from the developer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Windows 11 and a 4K display.

https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=134201#p501795 fixed it for me.

[image: VLC program properties high DPI settings.]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1189107)